# jQuery timing issue (ajax)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to send two values to a python script, if a certain button is pressed.

But there is a problem:
With `alert("test");` everything works perfectly. But without it, there is nothing send.

I think this is a kind of timing problem, but i cannot really think about what is the problem. 
Strange is, that i even can put the alert in front of the ajax function (but still in the `$("#submit").click` part) and it works perfectly.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="./jquery-1.4.4.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
/*<![CDATA[*/
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#submit").click(function(){
        jQuery.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "../../../cgi-bin/testCgi.py",
            data: {"nick" : $("#nick").val(), "msg" : $("#msg").val()},
            success: function (msg) {
                    alert("Data: " + msg);
            }
        });
        alert("test");
    });
});
/*]]>*/
</script>
```

Comment: I think this is caused by propagation of the javascript. Just replace the alert("test") with return false; might solve the problem

Comment: How do you *know* that nothing is sent? Are you inspecting the requests in the network tab or do you just assume nothing is sent because you don't see the second alert?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If `#submit` is a link element `<a href="...">` or a form button, you will need to cancel the default action.

```
$("#submit").click(function(e){

    // added following line and the parameter in the function definition
    e.preventDefault(); 

    jQuery.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "../../../cgi-bin/testCgi.py",
        data: {"nick" : $("#nick").val(), "msg" : $("#msg").val()},
        success: function (msg) {
                alert("Data: " + msg);
        }
    });
    alert("test");
});
```

If you do not do this, then the page follows the link, or submits the page.

Comment: Even better, if it is a submit button, would be to bind the handler to the `submit` event of the form.